# Entity Framework 6 - Detached entity prevent saving duplicate navigation properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

The method below takes some detached Nodes as an input parameter.  The goal is to load any existing Aliases from the database, insert missing Nodes into the database, and if the detached Node's Alias entity is already in the database, simply set it to the one of the database.

However, on SaveChanges(), it seems that the Alias that already exists in the database is inserted yet again.  How do I get around this?

```
internal async Task InsertMissingNodesToDb(INWatchNode[] nodes)
{
    if (nodes.Any(x => x == null)) {
        Trace.TraceError("Some null element in nodes array in InsertMissingNodesToDb().");
        nodes = nodes.Where(x => x != null).ToArray();
    }

    // De-dup nodes based on ID
    nodes = nodes.GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(y => y.FirstOrDefault()).ToArray();
    List<string> aliasNames = new List<string>();

    foreach (var node in nodes) {
        foreach (var alias in node.Aliases) {
            if (!aliasNames.Contains(alias)) {
                aliasNames.Add(alias);
            }
        }
    }

    using (var dbContext = Application.GetDbContext()) {
        dbContext.Aliases.Where(x => aliasNames.Contains(x.Alias)).Load();

        foreach (var node in nodes) {
            var entityNode = await dbContext.Nodes.FindAsync(node.Id);

            if (entityNode == null) {
                entityNode = node is NWatchNode ? (NWatchNode)node : new NWatchNode(node);

                for (int i = 0; i < entityNode.AliasEntities.Count; i++) {
                    var currentElement = entityNode.AliasEntities.ElementAt(i);
                    var loadedAlias = dbContext.Aliases.Local.
                        FirstOrDefault(x => x.Alias == currentElement.Alias);
                    if (loadedAlias != null) {
                        currentElement.Id = loadedAlias.Id;
                        currentElement = loadedAlias;
                        dbContext.Entry(loadedAlias).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                    }
                }

                dbContext.Nodes.Add(entityNode);
            }
        }
        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am suspicious of this section of code.

```
currentElement.Id = loadedAlias.Id;
currentElement = loadedAlias; // this seems pointless
dbContext.Entry(loadedAlias).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```

If you want the line in question to do something, I think you need to set `entityNode.AliasEntities.ElementAt(i)` to `loadedAlias` -- setting `currentElement` to `loadedAlias` is just overriding the local instance variable to point at `loadedAlias` and as such seems like pointless code -- you haven't informed the entity that one of its intended children should point to this instance with that line.  Something like the following might prevent the issue?

```
for (int i = 0; i < entityNode.AliasEntities.Count; i++) {
   var currentElement = entityNode.AliasEntities.ElementAt(i);
   var loadedAlias = dbContext.Aliases.Local.
         FirstOrDefault(x => x.Alias == currentElement.Alias);
   if (loadedAlias != null) {
         currentElement.Id = loadedAlias.Id;
         entityNode.AliasEntities.ElementAt(i) = loadedAlias;
         dbContext.Entry(loadedAlias).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
   }
}
```

Comment: `entityNode.AliasEntities.ElementAt(i) = loadedAlias;` does not compile :(

AliasEntites is an ICollection, so I get the message that the left hand must be a property or indexer.

Comment: I was wondering about that.  Maybe you need to remove `currentElement` and then add `loadedAlias` instead then?

Comment: You were right, I had to do a `entityNode.AliasEntities.Remove(currentElement);` insetad, then `entityNode.AliasEntities.Add(loadedAlias);`

By chance, do you know if Remove() goes off the hash to find an element to remove, or would it be using Id?